# Vercel 404 page on deployment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, hosting, vercel

I am trying to deploy a website to Vercel, and am having trouble with the build step and even when successfully deployed. I was getting the error "No Output Directory named "build" found after the Build completed" repeatedly, so I went in the settings and set Output Directory to '.next' and it started to deploy but now I get a 404 message at the domain. Im wondering if I have something wrong with my package.json, file structure, or idk.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-website",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx next dev",
    "build": "npx next build",
    "start": "npx next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@glidejs/glide": "3.5.2",
    "@next/font": "^13.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "next": "^13.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^18.12.1"
  }
}
```

File structure:

[image: file structure]

Build log:

```
> portfolio-website@0.0.0 build
> npx next build
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data...
info  - Generating static pages (0/3)
undefined
info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
info  - Finalizing page optimization...
Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      6.43 kB        79.6 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B            73.2 kB
└ ○ /404                                   181 B          73.4 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              76.2 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-3b5a00d5d7e8d93b.js   45.4 kB
  ├ chunks/main-11be7a5831576890.js        26.7 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-f8a9334f900a3d86.js  330 B
  ├ chunks/webpack-8fa1640cc84ba8fe.js     750 B
  └ css/53250905108bb3d4.css               2.98 kB
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
Build Completed in /vercel/output [17s]
Generated build outputs:
 - Static files: 113
 - Serverless Functions: 0
 - Edge Functions: 0
Deployed outputs in 1s
Build completed. Populating build cache...
Uploading build cache [57.27 MB]...
Build cache uploaded: 1.698s
Done with "."
```

and I have my Vercel settings as:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the output directory might be `/vercel/output`

Comment: Hmmm, when I set the Output Directory to '/vercel/output', I get the error again: "Error: No Output Directory named "output" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings." I put it back to ".next" and it works, but with 404. Its weird that in the build log it says my _app is 0B, so I guess its not accessing it correctly?

Comment: I’d recommend running the build command locally and seeing where it puts all the static assets

Comment: Solved it! I just changed the 'Framework Preset' in the Vercels settings to NextJS Framework and that did it... So simple and so much time wasted lol. I dont really understand it because I feel like my override for the output directory shouldve worked but w/e. This preset says "NextJS Default" for Output Directory.

Comment: LOL, I guess that’s one way to do it! Congrats